# Hiding/Displaying Forms (Checkbox forms) -- javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a plain-text representation of board of size X x Y using an underlaying 2D array presented on the screen. Each cell has either 1 or 0 as a value and there are preset array configurations that have users can choose that display on the board.

I want the users to be able to choose their own custom board configurations (i.e. picking which cells should be 1, while unchecked ones are 0). To do this, I simply set up a 16 x 16 table of checkbox inputs. At the bottom of this is a submit button where they can click to draw the board once they've chosen their configuration.

```
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

My question: How can I hide/display the checkboxes when necessary? I only want to display the checkbox inputs when a user specifically clicks that they want to create a custom layout. Once they select the boxes and press submit, I'll process the data, but I then also want to hide the checkboxes. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague. It trails off at the end. "Is this possible?" does not explicitly get into what went wrong with the code. Moreover, the statement "Once they select the boxes and press submit, I'll process the data, but I then also want to hide the checkboxes." does not correlate to what was explained above. Is this because there is ajax behind the scenes? Otherwise the post will refresh or redirect the page. Overall, you need to edit this question so that it is answerable without a lot of guesswork.

Comment: basically, is there a way to hide html forms/input after the user has submitted? also, is there a way to hide it until they choose to fill out the form, which in this case is a table of checkbox inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most basic case, you could simply have something like this:

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none; /* Make them initially hidden */
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Customize" onclick="showCheckboxes()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function showCheckboxes(){
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
    if(checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox'){
     checkboxes[i].style.display = 'inline');
    }
  }
}
```

You could obviously use similar logic for hiding the boxes again when some other event or interaction occurs. This assumes that all checkboxes on the page should be shown. If there are others on the page, you need to identify the ones you want to affect by name or class and check for that in the loop.

As usual, this would all be much simpler using a framework like jQuery.

Hiding the checkboxes before the form is submitted is not really a common thing to do. You could however have something like this for achieving it:

```
<form onsubmit="hideCheckboxes(); return true;">
```